# How to get overlay to cover the entire page even when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have an overlay that is triggered when clicking on an image. The issue with the overlay is that when you start to scroll, the background (light blue) disappears. I want this light blue overlay background to cover the entire page, scroll or no-scroll.

I've tried setting the height of the overlay to 100vh and 100%.

```
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body { padding: 152px 32px; position: relative; }

.overlay-text {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

iframe {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.popup {
  background: #dff9fb;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 16px;
}
```

```
<ul>

  <li>

    <a href=#popup1>
    <img class="new-tracks__image" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1774776/new.jpg"></a>

    <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
      <div class="popup">

        <h2>Jerry Craft - <em>"New Kid"</em></h2>

        <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/2yFC1YqdyPHnpCGJubdGaK" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>

        <div class="overlay-text">
          <p>The three Greystone kids always raced each other home when they got off the school bus, and Finn always won.</p>

          <p>It wasn’t because he was the fastest.</p>

          <p>Even he knew that his older brother and sister, Chess and Emma, let him win so he could make a grand entrance.</p>

          <p>Today he burst into the house calling out, “Mom! We’re home! It’s time to come and adore us!”</p>

          <p>“Adore” had been on his second-grade spelling list two weeks ago, and it had been a great discovery for him. So that was what it was called, the way he had felt his entire life.</p>

          <p>Emma, who was in fourth grade, dropped her backpack on the rug beside him and kicked off her red sneakers. They flipped up and landed on top of the backpack—someday, Finn vowed, he would get Emma to teach him that trick.</p>

          <p>“Twenty-three,” Emma said. There was no telling what she might have been counting. Finn hoped it was a prediction of how many chocolate chips would be in every cookie Mom was probably baking for them right now, for their after-school snack.</p>

          <p>Finn sniffed. The house did not smell like cookies.</p>

          <p>Oh well. Mom worked from home, designing websites, and sometimes she lost track of time. If today was more of a Goldfish-crackers-and-apple-slices kind of day, that was okay with Finn. He liked those, too.</p>

          <p>“Mom!” he called again. “Your afternoon-break entertainment has arrived!”</p>

          <p>“She’s in the kitchen,” Chess said, hanging his own backpack on the hook where it belonged. “Can’t you hear?”</p>

          <p>“That would mean Finn had to listen for once, instead of talking,” Emma said, rubbing Finn’s head fondly and making his messy brown hair even messier. Finn knew she didn’t mean it as an insult. He was pretty sure Emma liked talking as much as
            he did.</p>

          <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I want the light blue background of the overlay to take up the 100% of the height and width, even when scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just move: `background: #dff9fb;` from `.popup` to `.overlay`

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body { padding: 152px 32px; position: relative; }

.overlay-text {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #dff9fb;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

iframe {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.popup {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>

    <a href=#popup1>
    <img class="new-tracks__image" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1774776/new.jpg"></a>

    <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
      <div class="popup">

        <h2>Jerry Craft - <em>"New Kid"</em></h2>

        <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/2yFC1YqdyPHnpCGJubdGaK" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>

        <div class="overlay-text">
          <p>The three Greystone kids always raced each other home when they got off the school bus, and Finn always won.</p>

          <p>It wasn’t because he was the fastest.</p>

          <p>Even he knew that his older brother and sister, Chess and Emma, let him win so he could make a grand entrance.</p>

          <p>Today he burst into the house calling out, “Mom! We’re home! It’s time to come and adore us!”</p>

          <p>“Adore” had been on his second-grade spelling list two weeks ago, and it had been a great discovery for him. So that was what it was called, the way he had felt his entire life.</p>

          <p>Emma, who was in fourth grade, dropped her backpack on the rug beside him and kicked off her red sneakers. They flipped up and landed on top of the backpack—someday, Finn vowed, he would get Emma to teach him that trick.</p>

          <p>“Twenty-three,” Emma said. There was no telling what she might have been counting. Finn hoped it was a prediction of how many chocolate chips would be in every cookie Mom was probably baking for them right now, for their after-school snack.</p>

          <p>Finn sniffed. The house did not smell like cookies.</p>

          <p>Oh well. Mom worked from home, designing websites, and sometimes she lost track of time. If today was more of a Goldfish-crackers-and-apple-slices kind of day, that was okay with Finn. He liked those, too.</p>

          <p>“Mom!” he called again. “Your afternoon-break entertainment has arrived!”</p>

          <p>“She’s in the kitchen,” Chess said, hanging his own backpack on the hook where it belonged. “Can’t you hear?”</p>

          <p>“That would mean Finn had to listen for once, instead of talking,” Emma said, rubbing Finn’s head fondly and making his messy brown hair even messier. Finn knew she didn’t mean it as an insult. He was pretty sure Emma liked talking as much as
            he did.</p>

          <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the popup and the overlay height:100%, so you need to tell them to be "at least 100%" or min-height:100vh;

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 152px 32px;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay-text {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

iframe {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.popup {
  background: #dff9fb;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href=#popup1><img class="new-tracks__image" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1774776/new.jpg"></a>
    <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
      <div class="popup">
        <h2>Jerry Craft - <em>"New Kid"</em></h2>
        <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/2yFC1YqdyPHnpCGJubdGaK" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
        <div class="overlay-text">
          <p>The three Greystone kids always raced each other home when they got off the school bus, and Finn always won.</p>
          <p>It wasn’t because he was the fastest.</p>
          <p>Even he knew that his older brother and sister, Chess and Emma, let him win so he could make a grand entrance.</p>
          <p>Today he burst into the house calling out, “Mom! We’re home! It’s time to come and adore us!”</p>
          <p>“Adore” had been on his second-grade spelling list two weeks ago, and it had been a great discovery for him. So that was what it was called, the way he had felt his entire life.</p>
          <p>Emma, who was in fourth grade, dropped her backpack on the rug beside him and kicked off her red sneakers. They flipped up and landed on top of the backpack—someday, Finn vowed, he would get Emma to teach him that trick.</p>
          <p>“Twenty-three,” Emma said. There was no telling what she might have been counting. Finn hoped it was a prediction of how many chocolate chips would be in every cookie Mom was probably baking for them right now, for their after-school snack.</p>
          <p>Finn sniffed. The house did not smell like cookies.</p>
          <p>Oh well. Mom worked from home, designing websites, and sometimes she lost track of time. If today was more of a Goldfish-crackers-and-apple-slices kind of day, that was okay with Finn. He liked those, too.</p>
          <p>“Mom!” he called again. “Your afternoon-break entertainment has arrived!”</p>
          <p>“She’s in the kitchen,” Chess said, hanging his own backpack on the hook where it belonged. “Can’t you hear?”</p>
          <p>“That would mean Finn had to listen for once, instead of talking,” Emma said, rubbing Finn’s head fondly and making his messy brown hair even messier. Finn knew she didn’t mean it as an insult. He was pretty sure Emma liked talking as much as
            he did.</p>
          <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```